# Show that this parameterized family of operators is right-differentiable in its parameter

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space, $\kappa^{(i)}$ be a linear self-adjoint *contraction* (i.e. a bounded operator with operator norm at most $1$) on $H$ and $\lambda\in(0,1)$. It's easy to see that $$Q_\alpha:=(1-\alpha)\kappa^{(1)}+\alpha\kappa^{(2)}$$ is again a contraction on $H$ and hence the spectrum $\sigma(Q_\alpha)$ of $Q_\alpha$ is contained in $[-1,1]$. Thus, $$A_\lambda(\alpha):=(1-\lambda Q_\alpha)^{-1}(1+\lambda Q_\alpha)$$ is well-defined for all $\alpha\in[0,1]$.

> I guess it's trivial, but for the moment I can't see why $$B_\lambda(\alpha):=\lim_{t\to0+}\frac{A_\lambda(\alpha+t)-A_\lambda(\alpha)}t\tag1$$ exists for all $\alpha\in[0,1)$. In particular, with respect to which operator topology do we need to understand $(1)$? The strong or even the uniform operator topology?

Comment: I think for $\kappa^{(i)}$ to be a contraction we need

Comment: The map $\alpha\mapsto 1+\lambda Q_\alpha$ is differentiable for all $\alpha$, while if $\alpha\in (-\epsilon,1)$ it is valued in the invertible elements of $B(H)$ (which is an open set). The inverse map $A\mapsto A^{-1}$ is also differentiable on that open set, the product of two differentiable things is differentiable so $A$ is differentiable.

Comment: @RobertLewis I don't understand your comment. Could you clarify what you mean? $\kappa^{(i)}$ is assumed to be a contraction.

Comment: @0xbadf00d:  For some reason my entire comment didn't post.  I was trying to say that for $\kappa^{(i)}$ to be a contraction we need $\Vert \kappa^{(i)} \Vert < 1$, not with operator norm *at most one*; for example, unitary operators $U$ satisfy $\Vert U \Vert = 1$, but can't be contractions since $\Vert Ux \Vert = \Vert x \Vert$ for any vector $x$.

Comment: @RobertLewis This is a matter of terminology. Unfortunately, some authors call an operator contractive if its operator norm is strictly less than $1$, others if the norm is at most $1$. The latter call operators with norm strictly less than $1$ "contractive in the strict-sense".

Comment: @s.harp Almost everything is clear to me, but I don't understand your comment regarding $\alpha\in(-\epsilon,1)$ (what is $\epsilon$?) As pointed out in the question, $1-\lambda Q_\alpha$ is invertible for all $\alpha\in[0,1]$. Why do you know consider for which $\alpha$ the operator $1+\lambda Q_\alpha$ is invertible?

Comment: @s.harp Let $\Phi:\Omega:=\left\{L\in\mathfrak L(H):L\text{ is bijective}\right\}\to\mathfrak L(H),L\mapsto L^-1$ and $f:[0,1]\to\Omega,\alpha\mapsto1-\lambda Q_\alpha$. Then $\Phi$ is Fréchet differentiable and $(1-\lambda Q_\alpha)^{-1}=(\Phi\circ f)(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Looking at the inverse of $1+\lambda Q_\alpha$ instead of $1-\lambda Q_\alpha$ was a typo, however the reason why I also considered negative $\alpha$ is that in order to do analysis I need $0$ to be in the interior of the domain, hence we need to know that here we can widen this domain out to the left and retain smoothness / invertibility.

Comment: @s.harp So, the $\epsilon$ is only needed to obtain the existence of the limit in the question for $\alpha=0$, right? And just to be sure, everything is worked out with respect to the uniform operator topology, right?

Comment: Thats right, and yes these are statements about the norm topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $GL(H)$ denote the invertible elements of $B(H)$. Most of the work is understanding why the map $\iota: GL(H)\to GL(H)$, $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is smooth. These statements are classical statements about invertible elements of Banach algebras, the relevant ingredient here is the *von Neumann series*:

> Suppose $\|a\|<1$, then
>   $$(1-a)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n - \sum_{n=0}^\infty a^{n+1}=1$$
>   and $(1-a)$ is invertible. We will use this to show that $GL(H)$ is open and to calculate the differential of $\iota$.

To see that $GL(H)$ is open consider an $x\in GL(H)$ then look at the ball $B_{\|x^{-1}\|^{-1}}(x)$. If $y$ is in that ball then
$$\|1-x^{-1}y\|=\|x^{-1}(x-y)\|<\|x^{-1}\|\,\|x^{-1}\|^{-1}=1$$
hence the von Neumann series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-x^{-1}y)^{n}$ is the inverse of $1-(1-x^{-1}y)=x^{-1}y$. As $x$ and $x^{-1}y$ are invertible, so to is $y$.

The next step is to see that the map $\iota:GL(H)\to GL(H)$, $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is differentiable. First note that (for $h$ small enough):
$$(x+h)^{-1}-x^{-1}= (x(1+x^{-1}h))^{-1}-x^{-1} = ((1+x^{-1}h)^{-1}-1)x^{-1},$$
in particular we may evaluate $1+x^{-1}h = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (x^{-1}h)^n$ for $h$ small enough. Plugging that into the equation we just got retrieves:
$$\frac{\iota(x+h)-\iota(x)}{\|h\|} = - \frac{x^{-1}hx^{-1}}{\|h\|}+ o(h),$$
from which you may calculate that the differential of $\iota$ at $x$ exists and is equal to the map $h\mapsto -x^{-1}hx^{-1}$.

Finally we apply this to our problem. $\|Q_\alpha\|≤1$ for $\alpha\in[0,1]$ and the norm varies continuously with $\alpha$, hence there is some $\epsilon$ so that $\|Q_\alpha\|<\frac1\lambda$ for all $\alpha\in[-\epsilon,1]$ and a fixed $\lambda\in(0,1)$. Thus $1-\lambda Q_\alpha$ is invertible for all $\alpha\in [-\epsilon,1]$ and since $Q_\alpha$ is actually smooth in $\alpha$, the map $(1-\lambda Q_\alpha)^{-1}$ is also smooth in $\alpha$ (here $\alpha \in (-\epsilon,1)$).

Then the product $(1-\lambda Q_\alpha)^{-1}(1+\lambda Q_\alpha)$ is smooth on $(-\epsilon, 1)$, in particular smooth at $0$. One may evaluate the differential:

$$d_\alpha = (1-\lambda Q_\alpha)^{-1} \lambda(\kappa^{(2)}-\kappa^{(1)})(1-\lambda Q_\alpha)^{-1}(1+\lambda Q_\alpha) +(1-\lambda Q_\alpha)^{-1} \lambda (\kappa^{(2)}-\kappa^{(1)})$$

(One remark that might still need to be made, is that if $f, g :U\to B(H)$ are differentiable, then $f\cdot g$ is differentiable with differential $d_x(f\cdot g)[h]= d_xf[h]\cdot g(x) + f(x)\cdot d_xg[h]$, this calculation is the same as the usual product rule.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I'm missing something crucial, but it should be clear that $1-\lambda Q_\alpha$ is invertible for all $\alpha\in[0,1]$; why do we need it to be invertible even for all $[-\epsilon,1]$?

Comment: While it is possible to take differentials on boundaries, that can get kind of nasty. Thats why to remain in the more canonical "analysis on open sets" setting I expand the domain of $Q_\alpha$ to the left so that $0$ becomes an interior point.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Note that the question is on right-differentiability and hence this issue is not an issue here, but as you've shown the family is even differentiable.

Comment: Aren't we able to extend the differentiability to $\alpha=1$ (by the same argumentation)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to extend differentiability to $1$ (and a bit beyond that too)